# Are there any distributions to model a customer's spend per transaction?

Tags: probability, distributions, modeling

Are there any distributions that model a person's spending habits?

Comment: My answer is not about the distribution of the customer's spend, but there's a nice thing called market basket analysis. It uses algorithm (like APRIORI) to find probabilities and some metrics that tries to explains the relations between items inside a customer's basket

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.brucehardie.com/papers/bgnbd_2004-04-20.pdf) paper out and others like them from [this](https://marketing.wharton.upenn.edu/profile/193/research/?pubFilter=publishedPaper) guy. In my experience, it's the closest thing that's comprehensible (you'll need some decent probability/stats knowledge) and general (and works, again in my experience) to model customer lifetime value - which is very related to "spending habits".